# How does one create a repeating location-based reminder on their iPhone?

Tags: ios, reminders, geolocation

Typically, when a user creates a reminder on their iPhone they have the option of setting a 'repeat' schedule (e.g. Every Day, Every Week, etc). However, this option is only available when the reminder is set to notify them at a particular date/time.

On the other hand, if a user wants to create a reminder that notifies them when they’re arriving at or leaving a particular location, there is no 'repeat' option. This means if a user wants to create a reminder that reminds them, for example, to do something *whenever* they arrive home, they can’t. There’s just no way to make it repeat **every time** they arrive home.

Unfortunately, asking Siri to do this also doesn’t work.

Is there a way to create a repeating reminder based on location, not time?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mark the reminder as complete but simply dismiss the reminder, it will stay active and you will be reminded each time you arrive at (or leave) the location.

Answer (score 2):

As of the current version of iOS (iOS 11.4) this is not natively possible. However, you can do this by installing [IFTTT](https://itunes.apple.com/au/developer/ifttt/id660944638?mt=8).

IFTTT (or If This Then That) is a free web service that also provides an iOS app. More information about IFTTT generally is available on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IFTTT) and you can also visit the offical [IFTTT website](https://ifttt.com).

In a nutshell, however, IFTTT allows you to take advantage of thousands of applets/services that work with hundreds of apps.

To create a *repeating* location based reminder, follow these steps:

1. Download/install the [IFTTT](https://itunes.apple.com/au/developer/ifttt/id660944638?mt=8) app (**Note:** You will need to be running iOS 10 or later to install it)
2. Launch the app and either sign in with Google or Facebook, or sign up using an email address
3. Conduct a search for "Receive a notification when you enter a certain location"
4. Tap on the *Receive a notification when you enter a certain location* search result
5. Tap on the **Turn on** toggle switch (**Note:** After doing this your screen may slide over to present you with other applets you may like. If this happens, tap on the back arrow to go back to the previous screen.)
6. Tap on the cog at top right to configure this applet
7. Tap on the **Locate an area** field and enter the address of the location you want to trigger your reminder
8. Tap on **Save** at top right
9. Swipe up until you see the *Message* field
10. Enter the text you want to be displayed on your reminder notifications
11. Tap on **Done**
12. Tap on **Save**

It typically takes a few minutes for the service/applet to take effect, but once it does you’ll get a reminder *whenever* you arrive at the location you entered.

**NOTES:**

- There will be many similar applets that can perform the same action. This answer just provides one example of how users can achieve this functionality.
- Likewise, you’ll be able to find applets that work to remind you when you’re *leaving* a location.